# R Markdown Error: Error in tempfile(pattern = "_rs_rdf_", tmpdir = outputFolder, fileext = ".rdf") : temporary name too long

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working on RMarkdown and keep getting the following error when I run my code. W

```
Error in tempfile(pattern = "_rs_rdf_", tmpdir = outputFolder, fileext = ".rdf") : 
  temporary name too long
```

However, hen I paste the code in the console, it works. I can even knit the document successfully. What is the problem and how can one resolve this?

Comment: are you sure about `outputFolder` before using it? did you try to print it before making the `tempfile`

Comment: @rawr, how does one make sure about outputFolder before using it? I have the same problem and I did not set outputFolder. It appeared as the default.

Comment: @SusieDerkins i guess you could use `dir.exists(outputFolder)`, but the way i recreated this error was to make `outputFolder` hundreds of characters long

Comment: My question is more basic. What is outputFolder and how do you access it? When I run `dir.exists(outputFolder)` I get `Error in dir.exists(outputFolder) : object 'outputFolder' not found`.

Comment: @SusieDerkins it's just a character string file path the op uses as a temporary directory: `outputFolder <- '~/desktop/folder'` or `outputFolder <- file.path('~', 'desktop', 'folder')` for example

Comment: I'm having the same problem. And `outputFolder` isn't being defined by the OP. It's just referred to in the error. I have an R notebook. When I run it, I sometimes get that error just from a random chunk. Not trying to write anything. No `outputFolder` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a Windows computer. I solved it by shortening the name of my .Rmd. I think that the issue is related to the Maximum Path Length Limitation in the Windows API which are 260 characters. So by shortening the file name I made the path length shorter.